# Ruby on Rails: Action without View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what I think is a very simple problem. I'm coming from a PhP background, and used to do this all the time, so I may be looking at this the wrong way.

I am trying to create an ajax handler in RoR. When the user clicks a button, javascript fires off a POST, and gives the user feedback using the "success:" parameter of jQuery's ajax function.

The problem is, RoR is trying to load a view for the ajax handler, when I really just need a few lines in the controller to do the database work, and echo out a status code that will be interpreted by the user's javascript.

This is all just a mailchimp subscribe holding page, so I am only using the 'home' controller.

My Routes;

```
map.root :controller => 'home'
map.connect '/mcsubscribe', :controller => 'home', :action => 'mcsubscribe'
```

My Home Controller;

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # no content
  end
  def mcsubscribe
    print params[:email]
  end
end
```

And my testing javascript, just so you understand what's going on;

```
function mcSubscribe() {
    var email = jQuery("#signup_input_email").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://domain.com/mcsubscribe",
        data: "email=" + email,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I thought this would be a common problem, but I've googled around and only managed to find suggestions to redirect, as the user will never visit the /mcsubscribe page, that doesn't seem appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using

```
print params[:email]
```

will just print that value to the application logs, not into the response.

You want this:

```
render :text => params[:email]
```

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

You might need `render :nothing => true`

EDIT: misread your question, `render :text => "yourtext"` should fit your needs

Comment: Rendering nothing is not exactly what the OP wants to achieve. He wants to print just the value of `params[:email]`.

Comment: From your link, **render :text => params[:email]** works perfectly thanks! I knew it had to be simple.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5 you need to use 'plain':

```
render plain: params[:email]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something like this:

```
def mcsubscribe
  # Do something to unsubscribe
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(success_page) }
    format.js   { render :text => params[:email] }
  end  
end
```

If ajax is used, the `params[:email]` is send as text. If a HTML format is required (ie user clicked a link or filled in a regular form) a redirect is issued to tell the user the subscription has been successful.

Comment: I'll be doing all the user feedback clientside, fading out the form if I get a 'yes' back from the controller, and fading in the message.

Comment: Just showing for completeness sake :) And an advantage is that is also working for users without JavaScript (enabled), if there are any left...